# Updated EXIM4, now not using TLS due to validation failure

Tags: exim

I have a home server and updated the system drive to an SSD as it had been on a combination of USB and HDD for /home and /var.  Because the USB was on a previous version of Debian I have done a fresh install, which has also upgraded me to version 4.95 of EXIM, previously I was on 4.94.2.

Despite the same smarthost configuration, to use my ISP's SMTP server, it no longer uses TLS and gives a validation error.

/var/log/exim4/mainlog:

```
2022-04-12 03:30:25 1ne6I7-000AHw-MF TLS session: (certificate verification failed): delivering unencrypted to H=<DOMAIN> [<IP>] (not in hosts_require_tls)
```

The mail is still accepted unencrypted, but now mail from cron jobs is being flagged by my I.S.P. as spam.  The only change being messages being a `Received` header which has gone from being `with esmtpsa  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (Exim 4.94.2)` to just `with esmtp (Exim 4.95)`.  So presumably that difference is what is flagging it for extra attention.

I had been using the same self-signed key and certificate (with a 2013) timestamp as the previous installation.  I also tried generating a new pair with similar lack of effect.

After searching online for advice it was suggest to use a letsencrypt configuration so it could be validated.  I already use that, but it caused the same behaviour in EXIM.

This is my configuration

/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='<LOCAL DOMAIN>'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='<ISP DOMAIN>:587'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='true'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

/etc/exim4/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_settings:

```
MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = yes
MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<LOCAL DOMAIN>/fullchain.pem
MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<LOCAL DOMAIN>/privkey.pem
```

/etc/letsencrypt/archive/<LOCAL DOMAIN>/*15.*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root Debian-exim 1870 Mar 28 00:48 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/<LOCAL DOMAIN>/cert15.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root Debian-exim 3749 Mar 28 00:48 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/<LOCAL DOMAIN>/chain15.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root Debian-exim 5619 Mar 28 00:48 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/<LOCAL DOMAIN>/fullchain15.pem
-rw------- 1 root Debian-exim 1708 Mar 28 00:48 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/<LOCAL DOMAIN>/privkey15.pem
```

I also have `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` file with my SMTP login details, and which obviously is working to be sending mail at all.

is a domain which points to my home IP addrress.

The entries to the letsencrypt keys in 00_local_settings point to its symlinks that go to the current versions.  On those I have changed the group ownership so that EXIM can see the private key, but leave the permissions alone.

My previous working configuration was the same, but with the self-signed `exim.crt` and `exim.key` files in `/etc/exim4`, and so without the latter two lines in my 00_local_settings file.

I have also tried copying the letsencrypt files into `/etc/exim4` and naming them `exim.cert` and `exim.key` with the same permissions of 640 and nothing in 00_local_settings but it did not change anything.

What is particularly annoying is that as a final test I just deleted the keys with no configuration for them to see what would happen.  I got the same error, so I am cannot tell whether there is a problem with the keys I have used, or it is just not even seeing them at all.

Comment: look for clues in /var/log/exim4/mainlog and /var/log/exim4/paniclog

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `paniclog` and the line I gave is the only clue in `mainlog`.  The entries before and after the same as one the old Debian system, to confirm the connection and that the mail has been accepted.  But for the TLS error I included everything looks normal.  Not even a configuration error is logged anywhere when launching Exim.  I am completely lost what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have continued to research and I have found an answer, of sorts.  It was not clear to me whose certificate was being verified, I had assumed mine but realized it could be the one of the remote SMTP server.

Adding the entry below to `/etc/exim4/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_settings` disables verification, allows TLS to be used.

```
REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS = !*
```

This can be confirmed in a message header which now shows it being received `with esmtpsa  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (Exim 4.95)`

I assume this is what was happening before and that either Debian or Exim have changed the default to require verification since my initial configuration.

Presumably if the remote server uses a self-generated certificate it cannot be verified?

Comment: on re-reading th log line I was about to suggest the same cause.

Comment: It was a bit vague as to who was dong the verifying of whom as it gives no suggestion which server generated the error.  Given I searched a lot to find an answer without success, hopefully having posted it here means anyone else in s similar situation will find the simple solution.  Thanks for taking a look at the question though.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me mad.